Layout Label to wrap depending on other buttons
Considering the following code:
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="Gray"
                Spacing="10">
        <Editor x:Name="EditorText"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    HeightRequest="80"
                    BackgroundColor="White"/>
        <HorizontalStackLayout IsClippedToBounds="True">
            <Button Text="Button1"/>
            <Label FontSize="30"
                        Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference EditorText}}"/>
            <Button Text="Button2"/>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto">
            <Button Text="Button1"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" FontSize="30"
                        Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference EditorText}}"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="Button2"/>
        </Grid>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

Rendered depending on text size as:

How can I have a mix of the two lines of UI?
I want Button 2 close to the Label Text like in first line but if it exceeds the screen dimensions, the Label has to wrap like in second line.
I achieved this to work with code-behind calculation or using MaximumWidthRequest but I wonder if it exists a better solution using basic layout features..?

By setting HorizontalOptions to Start on the Grid, it will only take the necessary Width by default.
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto" HorizontalOptions="Start">
    <Button Text="Button1"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" FontSize="30"
        Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference EditorText}}"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="Button2"/>
</Grid>

That way the Label will only use the space it needs until it reaches its maximum width (or * in the ColumnDefinitions).

And if the text is long enough, it will reach its maximum width and the text will wrap:

